# How can I show every voice channel ID/name of a guild with DiscordJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to get and show all the voice channels name from guild.

That's my code, that not working

```js
client.on('ready', () => {

    client.channels.fetch().then(channel =>
    {
        console.log(channel.name)
    });

}
```

I'd like to list all names of voice channels (not text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the channels by type `ChannelType.GuildVoice` then map them to their name and id.

```js
// import or require ChannelType from discord.js

const allChannels = await client.channels.fetch();

const voiceChannels = allChannels
   .filter(ch => ch.type === ChannelType.GuildVoice);

console.log(
   voiceChannels
      .map(ch => `${ch.id} | ${ch.name}`)
      .join('\n')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to retrieve all channels using the channel cache of your client object. Then you filter by their type:

```
let voiceChannels = client.channels.cache.filter(m => m.type === 'voice');
voiceChannels.forEach(channel => console.log(channel.name));
```